# How to construct a vector based on lognormal parameters

Tags: r, broom

I have the following vector:

```
foo <- c(1.376, 1.132, 0.828, 0.88, 1.124, 0.955, 1.292, 0.995, 1.207, 
1.076, 1.085, 1.061, 0.918, 1.097, 1.505, 1.141, 1.001, 0.927, 
1.339, 1.07, 1.332, 0.951, 0.969, 0.904, 0.89, 0.942, 1.141, 
0.798, 0.856, 0.819, 1.055, 1.262, 0.919, 1.024, 1.034, 1.088, 
1.183, 1.214, 1.159, 0.952, 0.912, 0.812, 0.985, 1.097, 0.948, 
1.168, 1.052, 0.922, 1.06, 0.741, 0.797, 0.952, 1.024, 1.858, 
1.073, 1.107, 0.853, 0.931, 0.732, 1.218, 1.09, 1.177, 0.931, 
1.105, 1.115, 1.221, 0.948, 1.146, 1.201, 1.16, 0.542, 1.067, 
1.056, 1.013, 0.986, 0.971, 1.125, 1.127, 0.971, 1.167, 1.148, 
1.074, 1.089, 1.001, 0.715, 0.945, 1.319, 1.15, 0.861, 0.733, 
0.783, 0.704, 1.176, 0.766, 1.466, 0.88, 0.873, 1.906, 1.584, 
1.076)
```

And I can get the following parameter:

```
> broom::tidy(MASS::fitdistr(foo,"lognormal"))
     term   estimate  std.error
1 meanlog 0.03062806 0.01947609
2   sdlog 0.19476092 0.01377168
```

My question is how can I create the new vector (let's call it `bar`) of the same length as `foo`using the above parameter?

I tried this  (most probably wrong):

```
> rnorm(foo,mean=log(0.03062806), sd=log(0.19476092 ))
  [1] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 [39] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 [77] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: I don't understand. What do you want in the vector `bar`?

Comment: @MrFlick `bar` is just a placeholder of a new desired vector. see my update too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like this:

```
rnorm(foo,mean=0.03062806,sd=0.01947609)
```

The problem is that you are using `log` function inside the parameters of rnorm.

**Mathematically if you see the log(0.01947609) is a negative quantity ( -3.938568) for which in documentation it is specified it would give a NaN for cases where sd < 0 and would return a NaN**
I have given below the reference.

From the documentation of `?rnorm`:

> The numerical arguments other than n are recycled to the length of the
>   result. Only the first elements of the logical arguments are used.

and

> For sd = 0 this gives the limit as sd decreases to 0, a point mass at
>   mu. sd < 0 is an error and returns NaN.

**Sample of the output command:**

```
> rnorm(foo,mean=0.03062806,sd=0.01947609)
  [1]  0.032124378  0.042014230  0.045366499 -0.001474950
  [5]  0.061332938  0.008669682  0.019695857  0.042559250
  [9]  0.041862975 -0.010617882  0.067133856  0.016494814
```